# Show there exists a polynomial $ m_{T,v} \in \mathbb{F}[x] $ s.t. $ m_{T,v} | f $ for all $ f \in \mathbb{F}[x] $ that satisfy $ f(T)v = 0 $.

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, linear-transformations, minimal-polynomials

**Problem:** Let $ V $ be a finitely generated vector space over $ \mathbb{F} $, $ T: V \to V $ a linear transformation and $ 0 \neq v \in V $ a vector.  Show there exists a polynomial $ m_{T,v} \in \mathbb{F}[x] $ s.t. $ m_{T,v} | f $ for all $ f \in \mathbb{F}[x] $ that satisfy $ f(T)v = 0 $.

I have no idea what to do, since $ V $ is finitely generated then I know there exists some basis $ \beta = \{ v_1, ... , v_n \} $ where $ n = dimV $. I thought maybe I'd assume the negation which is $ \forall m_{T,v} \in \mathbb{F}[x]. \exists f \in \mathbb{F}[x]. m_{T,v} | f \land f(T)=0 $ but it doesn't seem to make the problem more solvable. I studied about minimal polynomials before approaching the question, but I don't know how to begin. Can you please help me?

Comment: It is very similar to the proof that a minimal polynomial exists. The set $\{f\in F[x]: f(T)v=0\}$ is clearly an ideal of $F[x]$. And every ideal in this ring is principal. Question is, are you familiar with this?

Comment: Ok thanks. I was given in the lecture just the theorem that a minimal polynomial exists without proof, I'll look into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $I=\{f\in F[x]: f(T)v=0\}$. Clearly the zero polynomial belongs to $I$. Also note that $I$ clearly has the following two properties:

$1$. If $f,g\in I$ then $f+g\in I$.

$2.$ If $f\in I$ and $g\in F[x]$ is **any** polynomial then $fg\in I$.

Now, if $I=\{0\}$ then simply take $m_{T,v}=0$. Otherwise, $I$ contains non zero polynomials. In this case let $m$ be a nonzero polynomial of minimal degree which belongs to $I$. We'll show $m$ satisfies what you need. Let any $f\in I$. We can divide it by $m$ with remainder. There are polynomials $q,r$ such that:

$f=qm+r$ and $\deg(r)<\deg(m)$

Since $f,m\in I$ it easily follows from the two properties I mentioned that also $r\in I$. But since $\deg(r)<\deg(m)$, it follows from the definition of $m$ that we must have $r=0$. Thus $f=qm$, and so $m|f$.